Getting 403 Forbidden for Internal XHR Requests
`@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    private final AdminLoginDetailService adminLoginDetailService;

    public SecurityConfiguration(final AdminLoginDetailService adminLoginDetailService) {
        this.adminLoginDetailService = adminLoginDetailService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf
                        .ignoringRequestMatchers(
                                "/admin/**", "/admin/trading-accounts", "/admin/algoSignals", "/vaadinServlet/**", "/VAADIN/**", "/frontend/**", "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**") // Allow Vaadin endpoints
                )
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(request -> HandlerHelper.isFrameworkInternalRequest("/*", request)).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/trading-accounts", "/admin/algoSignals").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/vaadinServlet/**", "/VAADIN/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/admin/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/trading-accounts", true)
                        .failureUrl("/admin/login?error=true")
                        .permitAll()
                );

        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(
                "/VAADIN/**",
                "/v-r/**",
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/manifest.json",
                "/icons/**",
                "/images/**",
                "/frontend/**",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**"
        );
        super.configure(web);
    }
}
`

I’m working on a Spring Boot application using Vaadin for the frontend and Spring Security for authentication. I'm encountering an issue where Vaadin's internal XHR requests are being blocked with a 403 Forbidden error after login.
`
The error details from the browser console are as follows:

FlowClient-341d667e.js:3 POST http://localhost:8085/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=3 403 (Forbidden)

FlowClient-341d667e.js:1 Server returned 403 for xhr
FlowClient-341d667e.js:1 Reconnecting because of XHR failure
FlowClient-341d667e.js:1 Reconnect attempt 1 for XHR
FlowClient-341d667e.js:3 Re-sending last message to the server...
FlowClient-341d667e.js:1 Sending xhr message to server: {"csrfToken":"f1fea950-67a6-4c85-9760-3c5b43b27602",
"rpc":[{"type":"publishedEventHandler","node":1,"templateEventMethodName":"connectClient",
"templateEventMethodArgs":["admin/login","","",null,""],"promise":0}],"syncId":0,"clientId":0}`

What I’ve Tried
1.Disabling CSRF entirely:
http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
2.Configuring CSRF to ignore specific Vaadin endpoints:
`http.csrf(csrf -> csrf
    .ignoringRequestMatchers(
        "/admin/**", "/admin/trading-accounts", "/admin/algoSignals", "/vaadinServlet/**", "/VAADIN/**", "/frontend/**", "/frontend-es5/**", "/frontend-es6/**")
);`

3.Allowing Vaadin internal requests using HandlerHelper.isFrameworkInternalRequest:
`authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
    .requestMatchers(request -> HandlerHelper.isFrameworkInternalRequest("/*", request)).permitAll()
    .requestMatchers("/admin/trading-accounts", "/admin/algoSignals").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
);
`

This also doesn’t resolve the problem.

Your additional configuration for CSRF and allowing Vaadin internal requests should not be needed as you are using VaadinWebSecurity class, that already does these settings for you.
